# JavaScript code is expected to return days of the current week only, but skips the second day

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code is expected to return days of the current week only, but skips the second day.

Here is the code:

```js
var curr = new Date;
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
var first = first + 1;
var second = first + 2;
var third = first + 3;
var fourth = first + 4;
var fifth = first + 5;
var last = first + 6;

var monday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toLocaleDateString();
var tuesday = new Date(curr.setDate(second)).toLocaleDateString();
var wednesday = new Date(curr.setDate(third)).toLocaleDateString();
var thursday = new Date(curr.setDate(fourth)).toLocaleDateString();
var friday = new Date(curr.setDate(fifth)).toLocaleDateString();
var sunday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toLocaleDateString();
//alert(monday+" "+sunday)
document.write(monday + " " + tuesday + " " + wednesday + " " + thursday + " " + friday + " " + sunday)
```

this is my output:
5/13/2019 5/15/2019 5/16/2019 5/17/2019 5/18/2019 5/19/2019
...notice 5/14/2019 is missing, could I get some help with this please?

Comment: if `first` equals the first day, why add `1` to it?

Comment: if first is initially 1, first = first + 1 makes first 2, second = first + 2 makes second 4 ... see the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as day 'zero' is Sunday You may have :

```js
var curr = new Date;
var zero  = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();   // Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
var first  = zero + 1; 
var second = zero + 2;
var third  = zero + 3;
var fourth = zero + 4;
var fifth  = zero + 5;
var last   = zero + 6;


var monday    = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toLocaleDateString();
var tuesday   = new Date(curr.setDate(second)).toLocaleDateString();
var wednesday = new Date(curr.setDate(third)).toLocaleDateString();
var thursday  = new Date(curr.setDate(fourth)).toLocaleDateString();
var friday    = new Date(curr.setDate(fifth)).toLocaleDateString();
var saturday  = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toLocaleDateString();


document.write( 'monday.....', monday    , '<br>' )
document.write( 'tuesday....', tuesday   , '<br>' )
document.write( 'wednesday..', wednesday , '<br>' )
document.write( 'thursday...', thursday  , '<br>' )
document.write( 'friday.....', friday    , '<br>' )
document.write( 'saturday...', saturday  , ' ==> ( not sunday ) <br>' )
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 to your first day, then incrementing from there incorrectly.

```js
var curr = new Date;
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
var monday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+1)).toLocaleDateString();
var tuesday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+2)).toLocaleDateString();
var wednesday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+3)).toLocaleDateString();
var thursday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+4)).toLocaleDateString();
var friday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+5)).toLocaleDateString();
var saturday = new Date(curr.setDate(first+6)).toLocaleDateString();
//alert(monday+" "+sunday)
document.write(monday + " " + tuesday + " " + wednesday + " " + thursday + " " + friday + " " + saturday)
```

Comment: 12th wasn't Monday. You should increment all days by 1 for a correct answer. But I think, author should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `first`, and then start adding to it.

Consider this code:

```
var n = 0;
var n = n+1;
var n2 = n+2;
```

you will end up with `n == 1` and `n2 == 3`.

Also, if you were using `let` instead of `var`, JavaScript would have caught this error for you.